# How can I add custom fonts in Figma linux

Tags: figma

I'm designing and prototyping an android app in Figma Linux but there is no way to add custom/desktop font in the application or in the web version. Figma only lists the Google fonts only. Please help me to solve this issue. I really need to add some fonts for my native language.

I don't know what to try as I couldn't find any documentation about this topic.